# What's the difference between sass update and sass watch

Tags: sass

What is the difference bewtween sass --update and sass --watch. Why can't I find any reference of all the common options that sass provide when you type in sass --help

Answer (score 1):

two things

1: if you type `sass --help` you should be getting a help page that looks something like this:

[image]

If not, you might have a deeper problem.

2: while it's not a obvious difference, the documentation for `sass --watch` says:

```
--watch     Watch files or directories for changes.
            The location of the generated CSS can be set using a colon:
                sass --watch input.sass:output.css
                sass --watch input-dir:output-dir
```

While the documentations for `--update` says

```
--update    Compile files or directories to CSS.
            Locations are set like --watch.
```

`--update` only compiles the files or directory, while `--watch` will watch for changes and recompile whenever the source files are modified.

Comment: what is the difference bewtween sass and sass --update then.  They both compile sscss to css

Comment: @JinxinNi the difference is  `sass` without options expects the syntax `sass input.sass output.css` and can only compile one file at a time while `--watch` and `--update` both expect the `input:output` format. Additionally, you have to use `--update` or `--watch` to compile directories of files.